# Shadow drop issues on three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry, shadow

I was trying to get some drop shadows with a plane geom.
But it didn't work well.

I looked through stackoverflow, though it didn't help me solve my problem.

I used

```
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
```

and  `mesh.castShadow = true;`, `mesh.receiveShadow = true;`

What did I miss ?

[you can see my code here](https://codepen.io/FJ--rllr/pen/awJrdQ)

(Plane on green and ground on yellow)

thanks for reading.

**Edit -**

I changed the plane with a thin box, thus it has a drop shadow now.

[Here it is](http://codepen.io/FJ--rllr/pen/awJrdQ)

Comment: For you plane mesh you use `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` which can't be affected by lights.

Comment: Okay, thanks I replaced with PhongMat. But I still got some problems: it draws some strange line on the ground plane https://codepen.io/FJ--rllr/pen/awJrdQ

Comment: [SpotLightShadow](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/shadows/SpotLightShadow), here you can read about shadows when you use `THREE.SpotLight()` in your scene.

Comment: and for rotation of the ground plane, use `plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;` (negative angle, thus you'll expose the front side of the plane to the light)

Comment: I have read the doc, But I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: read [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9315) thread

Comment: Did you figure it out? Your codepen looks OK to me.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes, now it looks fine, but before he used a plane instead of a thin box )

Comment: @TheJim01 yes the plane didn't had drop shadow. I don't know why but by changing it with another meshed it managed to work.